# Angular bootstrap accordion panel animation

Tags: css-animations, accordion, ng2-bootstrap

I use angular bootstrap accordion with pannels I want to create open/close animate for the pannels

```
<ngb-accordion>
  <ngb-pannel>
   <ng-template ngbPannelTitle><ng-template>
   <ng-template ngbPannelContent><ng-template>
  </ngb-pannel>
  <ngb-pannel>
   <ng-template ngbPannelTitle><ng-template>
   <ng-template ngbPannelContent><ng-template>
  </ngb-pannel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: If you use animations frequently, I recommend you https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/